# "Area code is not set" in var/log

Tags: magento2, log, error-log

I have this kind of error in logs that I have difficulties to understand.
I found some infos on "Area code is not set" errors in CLI, but not on the frontend side.
Have you suggestions ?

> {"0":"Area code is not set","1":"#0
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerNotification.php(78):
>   Magento\Framework\App\State->getAreaCode()\n#1
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121):
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Plugin\CustomerNotification->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#2
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#3
>   /data/www/.../.../generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Section/Load/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#4
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#5
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#6
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#7
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#8
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#9
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#10
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#11
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callParent('aroundDispatch',
>   Array)\n#12
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#13
>   /data/www/.../.../generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callPlugins('aroundDispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#14
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#15
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#16
>   /data/www/.../.../generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#17
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#18
>   /data/www/.../.../generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#19
>   /data/www/.../.../vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#20
>   /data/www/.../.../index.php(40):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#21
>   {main}","url":"/customer/section/load/?sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1547830571669","script_name":"/index.php"}

Comment: Have you installed any third party extension?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your modules have action process data in upgrade/install module.

Firstly: Find your modules process that script.

After that, add a area code to file update/install:

```
private $state;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\State $state) {
    $this->state = $state;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function execute() {
    $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND); // or \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, depending on your needs
}
```